# Kotlin data class file from json plugins giving error. How Can I Solve This

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, data-class

I'm using "Kotlin data class file from json" plugin. It generates this( part of that) according to my json data but ACT* is giving error. "Data class primary constructor must have only property (val / var) parameters" If I delete ACT* it's okay but I need it. How can I solve this error

```
data class Rates(
val `611`: Double,
val ABC: Double, 
val ACP: Double,
val ACT: Double,
val ACT*: Double
```

)

**Here is my json data**

```
{"success":true,"terms":"https:\/\/coinlayer.com\/terms","privacy":"https:\/\/coinlayer.com\/privacy","timestamp":1628580306,"target":"USD","rates":{"ABC":59.99,"ACP":0.014931,"ACT":0.015283,"ACT*":0.017178,"ADA":1.467363,"ADCN":0.00013,"ADL":0.01515,"ADX":0.498335,"ADZ":0.0023,"AE":0.1423,"AGI":0,"AIB":0.005626,"AIDOC":0.002271,"AION":0.1567,"AIR":0.001506,"ALT":0.565615,"AMB":0.039073,"AMM":0.009081,"ANT":4.5711,"APC":0.0017,"APPC":0.085581,"ARC":0.0169,"ARCT":0.00061,"ARDR":0.253864,"ARK":1.199199,"ARN":0.025474,"ASAFE2":0.4,"AST":0.243035,"ATB":0.017,"ATM":15.6446,"AURS":0.352867,"AVT":0,"BAR":0.00685,"BASH":0.0056,"BAT":0.710242,"BAY":0.0644,"BBP":0.0005,"BCD":2.54658,"BCH":583.974164,"BCN":0.000375,"BCPT":0.00318,"BEE":1.0e-6,"BIO":0.0008,"BLC":0.072132,"BLOCK":14.2395,"BLU":0.00054,"BLZ":0.1944,"BMC":0.067893,"BNB":352.078855,"BNT":3.95992,"BOST":0.048,"BQ":7.775e-5,"BQX":4.174322,"BRD":0.157009,"BRIT":0.03,"BT1":0,"BT2":0,"BTC":45430.909898,"BTCA":0.00036,"BTCS":0.01201,"BTCZ":0.000749,"BTG":58.422298,"BTLC":9,"BTM":0.073586,"BTM*":0.122609,"BTQ":0.01,"BTS":0.05217,"BTX":0.415943,"BURST":0.017348,"CALC":0.0006,"CAS":0.007,"CAT":0.122571,"CCRB":0.08888,"CDT":0.01943,"CESC":0.0037,"CHAT":0.003225,"CJ":0.000898,"CL":0.028,"CLD":0.02,"CLOAK":10,"CMT*":0.03954,"CND":0.013937,"CNX":1.996594,"CPC":0.0005,"CRAVE":0.4,"CRC":0.08475,"CRE":1.316485,"CRW":0.08996,"CTO":0.005,"CTR":0.017,"CVC":0.309381,"DAS":0.937816,"DASH":175.427844,"DAT":0.063536,"DATA":0.127116,"DBC":0.008631,"DBET":0.027656,"DCN":2.92587e-5,"DCR":155.798825,"DCT":0.00636,"DEEP":0.001,"DENT":0.00326,"DGB":0.056133,"DGD":598.341664,"DIM":9.4957e-5,"DIME":3.0e-5,"DMD":0.58782,"DNT":0.170526,"DOGE":0.253917,"DRGN":0.110212,"DRZ":3,"DSH":252.13175,"DTA":0.000726,"EC":50,"EDG":0.00634,"EDO":0.76521,"EDR":0,"EKO":0.002726,"ELA":3.2445,"ELF":0.266743,"EMC":0.05315,"EMGO":0.43382,"ENG":0.100394,"ENJ":1.559422,"EOS":4.484114,"ERT":0.2054,"ETC":58.251105,"ETH":3113.386705,"ETN":0.01595,"ETP":0.146283,"ETT":2.9,"EVR":0.104931,"EVX":0.519318,"FCT":1.577683,"FLP":0.003979,"FOTA":0.000363,"FRST":0.78001,"FUEL":0.000778,"FUN":0.019276,"FUNC":0.00061,"FUTC":0.004,"GAME":0.147055,"GAS":9.000715,"GBYTE":26.379517,"GMX":6.467e-5,"GNO":226.14,"GNT":0.350112,"GNX":0.02332,"GRC":0.0067,"GRS":10,"GRWI":10000,"GTC":8.537104,"GTO":0.03888,"GUP":0.001395,"GVT":3.784077,"GXS":0.39381,"HAC":0.001027,"HNC":0,"HSR":1.8723,"HST":0.0027,"HVN":0.03529,"ICN":0.1452,"ICOS":17,"ICX":1.110184,"IGNIS":0.025037,"ILC":0.098703,"INK":0.001054,"INS":0.280739,"INSN":0.0473,"INT":0.01821,"IOP":15.455555,"IOST":0.028468,"ITC":0.1,"KCS":10.727196,"KICK":0.000324,"KIN":5.9006e-5,"KLC":0.000703,"KMD":0.887073,"KNC":1.744903,"KRB":6,"LA":0.131507,"LEND":2.049671,"LEO":2.3023,"LINDA":0.000271,"LINK":23.988321,"LOC":6.042128,"LOG":0.060174,"LRC":0.292676,"LSK":3.976092,"LTC":163.809366,"LUN":0.27756,"LUX":2.09e-6,"MAID":0.60786,"MANA":0.781334,"MCAP":0.005398,"MCO":10.02,"MDA":0.752727,"MDS":0.008049,"MIOTA":0.90009,"MKR":3402.365996,"MLN":92.548,"MNX":0.028649,"MOD":1.095889,"MOIN":0.033073,"MONA":1.474326,"MTL":2.405,"MTN*":0.009575,"MTX":0.049281,"NAS":0.4535,"NAV":0.527787,"NBT":58.939123,"NDC":0.008989,"NEBL":1.279227,"NEO":46.105249,"NEU":0.154096,"NEWB":0.002604,"NGC":0.040132,"NKC":0.002252,"NLC2":0.599935,"NMC":5.867998,"NMR":39.07114,"NULS":0.505,"NVC":10,"NXT":0.015784,"OAX":0.181789,"OBITS":0.015,"OC":0.000791,"OCN":0.001251,"ODN":0.5,"OK":0.034525,"OMG":4.984751,"OMNI":4.0214,"ORE":0,"ORME":1.235715,"OST":0.008631,"OTN":0,"OTX":0.023,"OXY":1.452,"PART":3.951477,"PAY":0.075858,"PBT":586.463861,"PCS":0.019961,"PIVX":0.790372,"PIZZA":0.001,"PLBT":20,"PLR":0.040569,"POE":0.000182,"POLY":0.279,"POSW":0.48712,"POWR":0.298888,"PPC":1.002422,"PPT":2.507,"PPY":5.45,"PRC":3.0e-5,"PRES":0.219998,"PRG":1.299007,"PRL":0.061361,"PRO":0.275288,"PURA":0.25,"PUT":0,"QASH":0.07943,"QAU":0,"QSP":0.039067,"QTUM":10.544352,"QUN":0.006733,"R":1,"RBIES":1,"RCN":0.01627,"RDD":0.003507,"RDN":0,"RDN*":0.324446,"REBL":0.0033,"REE":1.0e-5,"REP":26.15,"REQ":0.07563,"REV":0.006956,"RGC":0.001,"RHOC":0.178417,"RIYA":0.090025,"RKC":5,"RLC":3.790396,"RPX":0.101757,"RUFF":0.007808,"SALT":0.768708,"SAN":0.256,"SBC":7,"SC":0.016842,"SENT":0.016,"SHIFT":0,"SIB":5.177,"SMART":0.006423,"SMLY":6.0e-5,"SMT*":0.011226,"SNC":0.036535,"SNGLS":0.011356,"SNM":0.187614,"SNT":0.087703,"SPK":0.0084,"SRN":0.012796,"STEEM":0.515582,"STK":0.003634,"STORJ":1.140747,"STRAT":0.717824,"STU":0.00019,"STX":0.682173,"SUB":0.003725,"SUR":0.25,"SWFTC":0.002364,"SYS":0.173986,"TAAS":10,"TESLA":0.019139,"THC":0.00954,"THETA":6.67714,"THS":0.00171,"TIO":0.085,"TKN":0,"TKY":0.000855,"TNB":0.003575,"TNT":0.007211,"TOA":0.002397,"TRC":6.2,"TRIG":0.899457,"TRST":0.04799,"TRUMP":0.055,"TRX":0.073483,"UBQ":0.274642,"UNO":118.3999,"UNRC":6.0e-5,"UQC":21.019,"USDT":1.001039,"UTK":0.298501,"UTT":0.44,"VEE":0.00857,"VEN":6.326613,"VERI":23.736235,"VIA":0.575561,"VIB":0.043259,"VIBE":0.014537,"VOISE":0.00018,"VOX":1239.10136,"VRS":0.1375,"VTC":0.565113,"VUC":9.9e-5,"WABI":0.208294,"WAVES":17.527728,"WAX":0.1739,"WC":0.045,"WGR":0.041793,"WINGS":0.049061,"WLK":0.0058,"WOP":0.046453,"WPR":0.010903,"WRC":0.000263,"WTC":0.6726,"XAUR":0.10301,"XBP":0.0027,"XBY":0.2889,"XCP":3.974871,"XCXT":0.095658,"XDN":0.001392,"XEM":0.180779,"XGB":0.0015,"XHI":0.001325,"XID":0.010924,"XLM":0.299302,"XMR":264.839976,"XNC":0.00018,"XRB":39.911795,"XRP":0.811623,"XTO":0.324858,"XTZ":3.239646,"XUC":0.13948,"XVG":0.026873,"XZC":4.96985,"YEE":0.001733,"YOC":0.00012,"YOYOW":0.014991,"ZBC":0,"ZCL":0.15762,"ZEC":129.858437,"ZEN":66.337135,"ZIL":0.092056,"ZNY":0.02,"ZRX":0.940716,"ZSC":0.000227,"611":0.389165}}
```

Comment: Try changing your variable names and use something like @SerialializedName Annotation

Comment: Yes, I think you are using unsafe variable names (611, ACT*) also.
Try using annotation for example @SerializedName("act1")

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is to use @SerializedName("") annotation befor your field names to be able to rename them to whatever you want and follow the naming principles

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Rates(
    @SerializedName("611") val x611: Double,
    val ABC: Double,
    val ACP: Double,
    val ACT: Double,
    @SerializedName("ACT*") val ACT2: Double
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your model class only, please try this code. Maybe it works!

```
class Rates{
    @SerializedName("ACT*")
    var abc: Double = 0.0
}
```